# Icon size on QComboBox's popup list

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qpixmap, qicon

I'm trying to make a simple `QComboBox` with a few color options. The easiest way I found so far was to make a `QPixmap` for each item, fill it with a color and use it as the item's icon:

```
this->colorComboBox = new QComboBox;
this->colorComboBox->setIconSize(QSize(100, 15));
QPixmap colorIcon(100, 15);
this->colorList.push_back(QColor(255, 255, 255, 255));
this->colorList.push_back(QColor(194, 169, 160, 255));
this->colorList.push_back(QColor(235, 206, 157, 255));
this->colorList.push_back(QColor(254, 121,   5, 255));
this->colorList.push_back(QColor(255, 195,  78, 255));
this->colorList.push_back(QColor(111, 203, 172, 255));
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->colorList.size(); ++i)
{
  colorIcon.fill(this->colorList.at(i));
  this->colorComboBox->addItem(colorIcon, QString(""));
}
```

The problem is, even though the color rectangle displays well on the button for the currently selected item:

[image]

It's displaying tiny for the items on the popup list:

[image]

It seems that the pixmap itself is always scaled down to a width of about 15px, no matter what size I choose for `setIconSize`.

I feel like this should be really simple to solve, but I've tried several things and nothing seems to work... Thanks in advance for the help.

**Edit:**

The `QSS` has the following for `QComboBox`. I tried changing `QComboBox::drop-down`'s width to 100px and the box itself gets larger, the icon still tiny.

```
QComboBox
{
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 4px;

  selection-color: #f58113;
  selection-background-color: #808080;
  show-decoration-selected: 0;
}

QComboBox:on
{
  padding-top: -10px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
   subcontrol-origin: padding;
   subcontrol-position: top right;
   width: 15px;

   border-left-width: 0px;
   border-left-color: #000000;
   border-left-style: solid;
   border-top-right-radius: 3px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the size after adding the item to the combo box.

Comment: It displays `OK` for me: http://i.imgur.com/5faGjUM.png. I think the problem is with your `QSS`. Could you post the `QSS` code you use for your `QComboBox`?

Comment: Setting the size afterwards doesn't help.

Comment: Added `QSS` code to the question.

Comment: I suppose that it is not full QSS, because it is not change background of popup menu, post absolutely full QSS code please.

Comment: @chapulina Still not the whole `QSS`: http://i.imgur.com/j72ZPSR.png
Can you please post all your `QSS` code? I recommend creating a simple blank project like this http://pastebin.com/k299j10c, try to isolate the problem and see where is its source. Chances are you're not looking in the right place and the problem is a totally different one.

Comment: The `QSS` is really long because it's a big project. I just emptied it and the problem disappears. I will try to isolate the problem, it's probably somewhere there. Any clue about where I should be looking?

Comment: Post QSS code which contains QListView or just post here full QSS, I'm sure that it can be very easy to find.

Comment: @chapulina Using `QSS` you can customize the items from inside a `QComboBox` by referencing the `QAbstractItem` inside them like this: `QComboBox QAbstractItemView { /* QSS code here */ }` and the list of items by referencing the `QListView` inside it like this: `QComboBox QListView { }`. There is a possibility that somewhere styling `QListView` or `QAbstractItemView` could interfere with your `QComboBox`. Try playing also with `QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item{ }` and `QComboBox QListView::item`.

Comment: I found the problem, it's in the `QSS` portion I posted. Taking out the `background-color: #808080;` line inside `QComboBox` fixes the size problem. No idea what's going on there...

Comment: @chapulina For sure there are conflicts in the QSS code and what you did fixes the conflict but there was no chance we could figure out from the info we were provided :). Chances are conflicts solved like this could reappear so what I recommend is to try understand the `QSS` code and clean it a bit. It's good that you fixed your problem, good luck!

Comment: So... Humm... The question now is, how can I keep the color for the whole project intact and fix this local problem I'm having?

Comment: @chapulina As I said...

Comment: @chapulina You can use `this->colorComboBox->setObjecgName("myCustomComboBox")` and reference it in `QSS` like this `QComboBox#myCustomComboBox { /* QSS code here */ }` and customize your background color only for your combo boxes that have the object name set to `myCustomComboBox` but this is a workaround/hack and I strongly don't recommend it...

Comment: I tried that, also tried setting it inline with `setStyleSheet`... But as long as I leave that line on the `QSS`, the size is small... I'm trying to understand why the bg color would affect the icon size...

Comment: Have you tried `QComboBox#myCustomComboBox { background-color: none; }` while keeping everything intact? It's important to place this code after other `QComboBox` related code.